# Zend Framework create project error

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-tool

I am new to the Zend Framework. I read the Zend Framework document. Here I saw to work Zend Framework must include the path in my php.ini, I believe that this is done because in my php info I saw include path is  C:\www\zend_frame\library

Also in document it says that to create a project I must run:

```
C:\> zf.bat create project quickstart
```

I want to create  a project in C:\wamp\www

In my command shell I ran:

```
C:\>wamp\www> zf.bat create project quickstart
```

But I got an error message (see below).

Then I tried another way:

```
C:\>wamp\www> C:\wamp\zend_frame\bin\zf.bat create project quickstart
```

Here I got the same error:

> Php.exe is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I also set the path in `My Computer` settings

Comment: can you please provide the error message ?

Comment: check that the path to php executable is correct in zf.bat

Answer (score 4):

The Zend Framework `zf.bat` script assumes that it can run "`php.exe`" without specifying the full path to that executable, and it will be found because you have set your `PATH` to include that directory:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php
```

Depending on the version of WAMP, the `php.exe` may be in a subdirectory for the version of PHP.  In that case you need to use a command something similar to this:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0
```

You should be able to figure it out from here.